# Is it safe to compare two floored doubles using the equality operator?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, equality

I know you should never compare floating point value using the `==` equality operator in .NET, but is it safe to do so if the two numbers were floored using `Math.Floor`?

I am working with a mapping program, and chunks of the map are stored in different "region" files. I can determine what region to retrieve by dividing the world coordinates by 16 and flooring the result, which gets me region coordinates.

I'm essentially asking whether or not two values that have the same whole number portion (e.g. 4.3 and 4.8) that are floored will be compared as equal using the `==` operator.

Comment: there is a related discussion (albeit F#) here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109057/f-net-calculation-error-using-the-system-math-floor-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general issue with floating point comparisons is that they can easily accrue rounding error.  When you take a value like `1.2` (which cannot be *exactly* represented as a decimal) multiply it by `100` and compare it for equality to `120`.  The recommendation is to always compare the difference like so:

```
var a = 1.2;
a *= 100;

if (a - 120 < 0.0001)
{
}
```

The `Math.Floor()` operation, however, always results in an integer value.  That is to say that any fractional values will be truncated, and the *exact* integer value will be left.

So, if your semantics *really are* to use a floor, you are safe.

However, if you are really trying to round, then use `Math.Round()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends on what you're trying to do.

That will tell you whether the floored values are equal - but if one input was *just a smidge* under 2, and one input was *just a smidge over* 2, then they'll be seen as different, despite the difference between them being potentially tiny.

Is that okay for your scenario? In some cases it will be, in some it won't.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is predicated on a faulty assumption.  It's perfectly safe to compare floating point values using == in .Net.  The only odd behavior associated with `==` and floating point values is that `Double.NaN` and `Single.NaN` when compared to themselves with `==` will return `false` (as dictated by the floating point specification).

Using `Math.Floor` doesn't make this situation any better.  If any of the special floating point values (`NaN`, `NegativeInfinity`, `PositiveInfinity`) are passed to `Math.Floor` they are returned unaltered.  So the comparison via `==` will still have the odd behavior ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx))

The main effect using `Math.Floor` will have is more floating values will compare equal to each other.  For example `7.1` and `7.5` will be equal after a `Math.Floor`.  That's not inherently any better but *could* be in the context of your application but it's hard to say it *will* be without more information..  Could you provide some more detail here on why you think `==` is unsafe?

Comment: I think this is more about rounding errors and thus the need for epsilon comparisons, and not about the non finite values.